# Como declarar um parâmetro de um objeto como nulo em C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-core

Possuo a seguinte classe em C#

```
namespace Projeto.Models
{
    public class Biblioteca
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Nome {get; set;}
        public Livro Livro {get; set;}
    }

    public class Livro
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Titulo {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Aí no controlador eu faço uma consulta no banco e crio um objeto com base nas informações que vem dele, e após isso eu crio um JSON com todas as informações geradas

```
List bibliotecas = new List();

// comandos de SQL e bla bla bla...

while (dados.Read ())
{
    Biblioteca biblioteca = new Biblioteca();

    biblioteca.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dados["IdBiblioteca"]);
    biblioteca.Nome = Convert.ToString(dados["Nome"]);
    biblioteca.Livro = new Livro
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(dados["IdLivro"]),
        Descricao = Convert.ToString(dados["Titulo"])
    };

    bibliotecas.Add (biblioteca);
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bibliotecas);
```

A grande questão é que o objeto livro não é obrigatório, ou seja, pode vir do banco para as colunas dele valores nulos, só que quando isso acontece o sistema me retorna o seguinte erro.

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Existe alguma forma de fazer com que esses dois parâmetros do objeto livro recebam null quando os valores não existirem? Porque precisaria enviar os valores posteriormente indicando que existem para que o javascript não se perca depois.

Preciso que o JSON tenha sempre as chaves de ID e Título, mesmo que os valores desses dois sejam nulos. Consigo fazer isso? Já tentei de várias formas mas até agora sem sucesso. :(

Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: Se vc fizer isso: `biblioteca.Livro = dados["IdLivro"] == null ? null :  new Livro(){... }` não resolve?

Comment: Não, infelizmente não resolve

Comment: Mateus... em que linha dá o erro?

Comment: Leandro, neste caso ele não me dá um erro físico, mas sim lógico, eu preciso que o JSON tenha as duas chaves Id e Título. Sendo assim, tem que ser:
{
    Id: null,
    Título: null:
}
ou
{
    Id: 123,
    Título: "Harry Potter"
}

Comment: @MateusMattieloNickhorn passar chave nula no JSON não é uma boa prática.

Answer (score 3):

Mateus, neste caso é necessário tratar o valor do seu DataReader.

Utilize o comando [Convert.IsDBNull](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.convert.isdbnull?view=netframework-4.8) para verificar se o valor recebido é nulo.

Altere a propriedade Id do Livro para o tipo int?, de forma a aceitar valores nulos:

```
public int? Id { get; set; }
```

Ao setar o valor da propriedade Livro, faça a validação utilizando o comando IsDBNull:

```
biblioteca.Livro = new Livro 
{ 
    Id = Convert.IsDBNull(dados["IdLivro"]) ? (null as int?) : Convert.ToInt32(dados["IdLivro"]), 
    Descricao = Convert.IsDBNull(dados["Titulo"]) ? null : Convert.ToString(dados["Titulo"]) 
};
```

Comment: Seria algo assim?

biblioteca.Livro = new Livro
    {
        Id = Convert.DBNull(dados["IdLivro"]),
        Descricao = Convert.ToString(dados["Titulo"])
    };

ele diz que eu não consigo converter de Int para null

Comment: Observe o seguinte: na sua classe Livro, a propriedade Id não aceita nulo. Para Id aceitar nulo você deve declará-lo assim: 
public int? Id { get; set; }

Em segundo lugar, para validar com IsDBNull você poderia fazer assim:
biblioteca.Livro = new Livro
    {
        Id = Convert.IsDBNull(dados["IdLivro"]) ? null : Convert.ToInt32(dados["IdLivro"]),
        Descricao = Convert.IsDBNull(dados["Titulo"]) ? null : Convert.ToString(dados["Titulo"])
    };

Porém esta validação somente funciona caso o seu campo Id seja do tipo int?. Caso contrário, você será obrigado a passar algum valor.

Comment: Efetuei o que você me disse, declarei na classe o int? e fiz o operador ternário, mas agora ele me retorna isso:

Erro CS0173 Tipo de expressão condicional não pode ser determinado porque não há conversão implícita entre "<nulo>" e "int"

Comment: Uma outra questão, se na classe livro eu declarar um string?, ele me retorna o erro CS8652 que eu já documentei por aqui no post, segue novamente:

Erro CS8652 O recurso 'tipos de referência que permitem valor nulo' está atualmente na Versão Prévia e sem suporte. Para usar os recursos da Versão Prévia, use a versão de linguagem da "versão prévia"

Comment: Tente assim:
biblioteca.Livro = new Livro { Id = Convert.IsDBNull(dados["IdLivro"]) ? (null as int?) : Convert.ToInt32(dados["IdLivro"]), Descricao = Convert.IsDBNull(dados["Titulo"]) ? (null as int?) : Convert.ToString(dados["Titulo"]) };

Comment: Lamentavelmente não

Erro CS0266 Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "int?" em "int". Existe uma conversão explícita (há uma conversão ausente?)

Comment: Cara, eu já te orientei a colocar a propriedade Id aceitando valores nulos:  public int? Id { get; set; }

Comment: Peço desculpas Guilherme, eu já fiz tanta alteração que não havia me dado conta que faltava a configuração ali. Mas mesmo assim eu continuo tendo problemas, com o ID que é um int funcionou 100%, mas e para o título que é uma string? Se eu fizer "string?",(como já reportei anteriormente) o sistema me retorna o erro CS8652 O recurso 'tipos de referência que permitem valor nulo' está atualmente na Versão Prévia e *sem suporte*. Para usar os recursos da Versão Prévia, use a versão de linguagem da "versão prévia"

Não queria usar esta versão prévia, seja lá qual for ela, alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Eu enviei o exemplo com erro. Já editei a postagem com a correção.

Comment: @GuilhermeSouza acredito que para fazer esse ternário a condição de negação tem que ter cast também.. ficaria tipo: ```Convert.IsDBNull(dados["IdLivro"]) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(dados["IdLivro"])```

Answer (score 2):

Se a propriedade que recebe o objeto o tipo `Livro` que pode ser nula, basta você indicar isso na declaração da sua classe.

```
public class Biblioteca
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public Livro? Livro {get; set;}
}
```

ou

```
public class Biblioteca
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public Nullable<Livro> Livro { get; set; }
}
```

E no seu caso, adicione verificação antes de tentar adicionar algum valor para ele.

```
biblioteca.Livro = dados["IdLivro"] != null ? new Livro
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(dados["IdLivro"]),
    Descricao = Convert.ToString(dados["Titulo"])
} : null;
```

Comment: Tentei fazer isso mas o Visual Studio me retorna esse erro

Erro CS8652 O recurso 'tipos de referência que permitem valor nulo' está atualmente na Versão Prévia e *sem suporte*. Para usar os recursos da Versão Prévia, use a versão de linguagem da "versão prévia".

Comment: retorna que erro?

Comment: Erro CS8652 O recurso 'tipos de referência que permitem valor nulo' está atualmente na Versão Prévia e *sem suporte*. Para usar os recursos da Versão Prévia, use a versão de linguagem da "versão prévia".

Comment: Atualizar a linguagem no seu CSPROJ não remove esse erro de CS não? tipo ```<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>```

Answer (score 1):

Ajuste as Models:

Na model **Biblioteca**, criar um construtor que inicia **Livro**.

```
public class Biblioteca
{
    public Biblioteca()
    {
        Livro = new Livro();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Livro Livro { get; set; }
}
```

Na model **Livro**, permitir Null no atributo **Id**.

```
public class Livro
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
}
```

No controlador aplicar verificação de Null para "IdLivro".

```
var bibliotecas = new List<Biblioteca>();

// comandos de SQL e bla bla bla...
// Provavelmente dados é um SqlDataReader

while (dados.Read ())
{
    Biblioteca biblioteca = new Biblioteca();

    biblioteca.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dados["IdBiblioteca"]);
    biblioteca.Nome = Convert.ToString(dados["Nome"]);
    if(!dados.IsDBNull(dados.GetOrdinal("IdLivro")))
    {
        biblioteca.Livro.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dados["IdLivro"]);
        biblioteca.Livro.Descricao = dados["Titulo"];
    }

    bibliotecas.Add (biblioteca);
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bibliotecas);
```

Ou seja, a Biblioteca já nasce com um Livro mas com seus atributos Null.